# Join tables and get data from both of them

Tags: asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc

I have been trying to get data from the table I have joined to the main user table, the second table is to hold images.  My current code posted below, only return the ImageID from the table when I want to be retrieving the ImagePath field, just to note this is a separate table as the user can add many images.

These are the models:

```
[Table("accountInfo")] // Table name
public class accountInfo
{
    [Key]
    public int AccountID { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int UserIdent { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }    
    public virtual ICollection<UserImages > UserImages { get; set; }
}

[Table("UserImages")] // Table name
public class UserImages 
{
    [Key]
    public int ImageID { get; set; }
    public int AccountID { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    public string ImageDesc { get; set; }
    public int ProfileImage { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    int id = (int)WebSecurity.CurrentUserId; 
    var users = db.AccountInformation.Include(c => c.UserImages).Where(c => c.UserId == id);

    return View(users.ToList());                 
}
```

I am assuming I have gone wrong in the models set up.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Are there two tables - "accountInfo" and "AccountInformation" ?

Comment: I used visual webdevelopers scaffolding and this is what that put, it does appear to be directly associated with accountInfo.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = db.AccountInformation.Include(c => c.UserImages.Select(x => x.AccountId)).Where(c => c.UserId == id);
```

Comment: It gives an error saying 'cannot convert lambda expression to type string because it is not a delegate type'

Comment: Thanks scott that has removed the lambda error, however still having the same issue in the view where I cannot access the field ImagePath. It is saying it is not part of the current context? I am using Razor - @html DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Imagepath)